# Limiting scope of JQuery selection with nested, repeating element structure

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, nested

Given a repeating, nested element structure, for example:

```
<div class="A">

  <span class="B></span>
  <span class="B></span>

  <span class="B">
     <div class="A">
        <span class="B"></span>
     </div class="A">
  </span>

</div>
```

How can I select the last `<span class="B"></span>` that is a direct child of the root `<div class="A"></div>` element?

I tired:

```
div.A > class.B
```

...but (correctly) this also matches the last element which is not a direct child of the root `<div class="A"></div>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could either add some id, classes, or a data-level object in order to make the nesting search easier, or you could do this slightly hackish version:

```
$('div.A').first().children('span.B').last();
```

I would suggesting adding a data-level, id, or other class to handle the level though.

For example, change your HTML to:

```
<div class="A" data-level="first">

  <span class="B" data-level="second"></span>
  <span class="B" data-level="second"></span>

  <span class="B" data-level="second">
     <div class="A" data-level="third">
        <span class="B" data-level="fourth"></span>
     </div>
  </span>

</div>
```

and you can do things like:

```
$('span.B[data-level="second"]').last();
```

etc.

Comment: By data-level do you mean I should use some allowed existing attribute of a `<span>` element and use it to store the depth of the `<span>` element? For example in the `title` attribute? I can't really add an ID since IDs must be unique.

Comment: see my edit. your html was slightly malformed i fixed that up too

Comment: is `data-level` an allowed attribute?

Comment: yep. in jquery you can access it like: $('span.B').data('level'); or like $('span.B').attr('data-level');

Comment: @Jack - You can use any data-xxxx attribute.  That's a new HTML5 standard for custom attributes that is 100% backwards compatible with old browsers.

Comment: For me at least, I needed an extra step since (using your example): 
`$('span.B[data-level="second"]').last();` 
would select the correct element, but it still includes the nested the element:
`<span class="B" data-level="fourth"></span>`
I needed some extra step to filter by ':last' a second time.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has the `:last` selector.  It's still not entirely clear to me which object you're trying to select.

If you want the last `<span class="B"></span>` that is a direct child of the root `<div class="A">`, then you have these options:

1) Give the root an identifying class:

```
<div class="A root">

  <span class="B></span>
  <span class="B></span>

  <span class="B">
     <div class="A">
        <span class="B"></span>
     </div>
  </span>

</div>
```

And this selector:

```
A.root > .B:last
```

2) Specify the parent of the root object to identify it:

```
body > .A > .B:last
```

3) Use some code to identify the root object:

```
$(".A").filter(function() {
    // filter out items that have an "A" class as a parent
    return($(this).parents(".A").length == 0);  
}).children(".B:last");
```

Comment: The problem is the pattern repeats. It is generated with recursive function calls. I cannot add anything unique to the root element.

Comment: @Jack - perhaps I don't understand what you're trying to do then.  I thought you wanted the last B element that was a direct child of the top level "A" element.  To do that, you HAVE to identify the top level "A" element somehow.  My new option 3) uses code to identify it.  If you're trying to do something different, then please explain some more what you're trying to do as it is not particularly clear.